# What's the difference between _int_malloc and malloc (in Valgrind)

Tags: memory-management, malloc, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am amazed that I can't find any document stating the difference between `_int_malloc` and `malloc` in the output of Valgrind's `callgrind` tool.

Could anybody explain what's their difference?

Furthermore, I actually write C++ code, so I am using exclusively `new` not `malloc`, but in the callgrind output only mallocs are showing up.

Comment: Which platform is this? And which version of Valgrind? Lastly, how are you linking your application?

Answer (score 5):

The `malloc` listed in the `callgrind` output will be the implementation of `malloc` provided by the glibc function `__libc_malloc` in the file [glibc/malloc/malloc.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=malloc/malloc.c;hb=refs/heads/master).

This function calls another function, intended for internal use only, named `_int_malloc`, which does most of the hard work.

As writing standard libraries is very difficult, the authors must be very good programmers and therefore [very lazy](https://web.archive.org/web/20180510170935/http://threevirtues.com/). So, instead of writing memory allocation code twice, the `new` operator calls `malloc` in order to get the memory it requires.